# Firebase set method not working

Tags: database, node.js, firebase

Creating a node app in Firebase, and having a lot of trouble "setting" values. I have a sneaking suspicion this has to do with permissions or something (I haven't set any read/write permissions of my own), but not sure. Simplified code below:

```
var Firebase = require("firebase");
var Scope = new Firebase('https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/');

Scope.child("users").child(queue.uid).on('value', function(user) {

    console.log(user.val()); // Works fine
    user.set({id: 123}); // Fails, "Object has no method 'set'"

});
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `user` variable being passed into the `value` callback is actually a [snapshot](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/datasnapshot/index.html)--not a [Firebase ref](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/index.html). So there is no set method.

However, the ref is available on the snapshot by calling .ref():

```
Scope.child("users").child(queue.uid).on('value', function(user) {
  console.log(user.val()); // Works fine
  user.ref().set({id: 123}); // Yay!
});
```